# How are thread IDs calculated?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading

I'm analysing a dumpfile of a multi-threaded C++ application, using Visual Studio.
In order to see the thread IDs, I check the `ID` column of the `Threads` debug window.
Normally, when I do this, I see the thread IDs to be around:

```
Minimumvalue : ±10-100
Maximumvalue : ±10.000-100.000
```

Now, the values of the thread ID are:

```
12604                                // first value seems to be ok
Some values in the hundred-thousands // that still seems to be ok
Some values in the millions          // this is becoming very large
6162348
```

This makes me think that something is wrong: normally those thread IDs are not that large, but in order to investigate this issue further, I need to know how thread IDs are calculated. (For your information, there are 249 threads within this application, and the application runs in an environment with other multi-threaded applications).

Does anybody know how thread IDs are calculated in a Windows environment?

Comment: Implementation defined?

Comment: What are you really trying to do?

Comment: How are you finding the values of thread ID?

Comment: On win32 thread id is an handle https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/markrussinovich/2009/09/29/pushing-the-limits-of-windows-handles/

Comment: @selbie: I'm not programming anything: I'm working as a support engineer and I'd like to understand the values I see in a dumpfile.

Comment: @P.W: I edited my question accordingly.

Comment: They're arbitrary numbers and have no meaning in themselves.

Comment: @ZangMingJie: when reading the blog you mentioned, this means that (in case thread IDs are always becoming larger) that my customer is half-way getting the error "No more threads can be created in the system". On the other hand, Jonathan just mentioned that the number are arbirary, so I'm not half-way of the mentioned error message.

Comment: This is clearly an XY problem.  Are you trying to say that the actual problem you're seeing is that no more threads can be created, and your question is what can cause this?

Comment: The situation is: I see that those numbers are higher than usual and I wonder what that means, and what I might expect.

Comment: Thread ID numbers created by windows are basically arbitrary for all intents and purposes, You normally see the majority within a power of 10 of each-over but it's meaningless

Comment: NT client Identifiers (for Process and Thread objects) are assigned out of a dedicated system handle table. Like all kernel handle values, they're always a multiple of 4. Getting kernel handle values in the millions is rare considering how a handle table grows and reuses values.